Weird Behaviour In Emmbedding SvelteKit Into Rust May Minihttp
so I’m trying to embed SvelteKit into Rust's may minihttp. However, I’m encountering this problem. Whenever I visit the home route "/", it always gives the following error in browser console
Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
localhost/:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: http://localhost:8500/_app/immutable/entry/start.B3UW3XMX.js

But I've set the content type to text/html for the HTML file and the others dynamically follow their respective MIME types.
And the display changes unpredictably when I visit the home page. When I visit the home page for the first time, the page appears blank like this

When I click the refresh button, it shows the favicon image like this

And when I click refresh again, it shows the JavaScript code as text like this

And when I click refresh again, it goes back to displaying a blank white page and if I refresh again, then it shows the favicon, and keeps looping between those three types of views when I click refresh again and again.
There’s no issue with the SvelteKit code itself, as it previously worked fine when I implemented it with Rust Axum. However, it doesn't work with Rust may minihttp. If the index.html file is just regular HTML and JavaScript, it works. But when I switch the index.html to the one from SvelteKit, it doesn't. My prediction is that the problem lies in route handling, content-type, and response, but I've already tried to address these in the code, but it still results in weird behavior
Is there something wrong with my code? Here is the code
use std::io;
use may_minihttp::{HttpService, HttpServiceFactory, Request, Response};
use rust_embed::RustEmbed; 
use mime_guess;

#[derive(RustEmbed)]
#[folder = "src/svelte/build/"]
struct Assets;

struct Router;

impl HttpService for Router {
    fn call(&mut self, req: Request, rsp: &mut Response) -> io::Result<()> {
        match req.path() {
            _ => {
                let path = req.path().trim_start_matches('/');
                if path.is_empty() || path == "index.html" {
                    if let Some(content) = Assets::get("index.html") {
                        rsp.header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
                        rsp.body_mut().extend_from_slice(&content.data);
                    }
                }
                
                else if let Some(content) = Assets::get(path) {
                    let mime = mime_guess::from_path(path).first_or_octet_stream();
                    let content_type: &'static str = Box::leak(format!("Content-Type: {}", mime).into_boxed_str());
                    println!("{}", content_type);
                    rsp.header(content_type);
                    rsp.body_mut().extend_from_slice(&content.data);
                }
                
                else if path.contains('.') {
                    rsp.status_code(404, "Not Found");
                }

                else if let Some(content) = Assets::get("index.html") {
                    rsp.header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
                    rsp.body_mut().extend_from_slice(&content.data);
                }
            }
        }
        Ok(())
    }
}

struct HttpServer;

impl HttpServiceFactory for HttpServer {
    type Service = Router;

    fn new_service(&self, _: usize) -> Self::Service {
        Router 
    }
}

fn main() {
    may::config().set_pool_capacity(500).set_stack_size(0x1000);
    let http_server = HttpServer;
    let server = http_server.start("0.0.0.0:8800").unwrap();
    server.join().unwrap();
}


Your content_type with the static and Box::Leak might be the cause. You are also leaking memory there with each request. You don't want to send index.html in else. Send a 404 response. Unit testing and Debugging is cool btw. ;-)

How to set the content type without static and Box::leak? I used them due to lifetime problem. My flows are : remove /, return index.html if resulted path is empity, then components & favicon based on the file name, then if still doesn't meet those 2 condition check if there's a dot (.), if there is (.) then return 404 because the file isn'T found, else return index.html for other page routes. My SvelteKit already handled undefined pages routes as 404. But still not working. Is there something wrong? Yeah, I'm also still keep learning debugging and unit testing while trying to fix this problem

@Markus I have updated the code, but still don't know how to fix lifetime problem without using static dan Box::leak in my case. Do you have suggestion for this? the rsp.header expects &str

Load your latest code to rust playground and post a link, I'll edit it there.

And a rercursive directory listing of the content in svelte/build/...

@Markus Here is my newest code version and path lists in vector https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=836cb4ea7361a170f71f8c55ecc35376

I've uploaded a working project to https://github.com/kolbma/may_embed_svelte_sample/
There are multiple possibilities how the Svelte frontend code could be built.
I've just hacked together some static sample files in src/svelte/build/ for the project.
But I think with const REDIRECT_INDEX setting it should work like you need it for your own src/svelte/build/.
It is described in code comment.
Because mayhttpd needs a &'static str for setting an header and you don't want to leak memory maybe for each request on Box::leak, I've provided 2 possibilities in mime_mapper.rs.
The 1st uses mime_guess crate like in your provided question to Box::leak. But stores each &'static str lookup-able in a global static map.
So there is only a leak once for each mime-type and it is reusable over all requests.
There is also not the problem like in the question with race conditions, one request sets the static to a new value, while the older request hasn't finished its response and uses the newly set different content-type of the newer request.
The 2nd possibility is mime_map() function. There you provide a matcher with returning fixed &'static str. So you would have to prepare it for your required content-types in the project. Although much more seems not to be required.
This could also be changed to not use mime_guess at all, but something like let ext = path.rsplit_once('.').unwrap().1; and match on the path extensions directly.
This version of mime_map() is already checked in the above Github-repo.
The code part looks like this...
main.rs:
use std::io;

use log::{debug, info};
use may_minihttp::{self as mayhttp, HttpServiceFactory as _};
use mime_mapper::MimeMapper;
use rust_embed::RustEmbed;

mod mime_mapper;

/// true: redirect directory paths to /
/// false: use /index.html content for no index.html in sub-directories (a/ or a/index.html)
const REDIRECT_INDEX: bool = true;

const SERVER_ADDRESS: &str = "0.0.0.0:8800";

#[derive(RustEmbed)]
#[folder = "src/svelte/build/"]
struct Assets;

struct Router;

impl mayhttp::HttpService for Router {
    fn call(
        &mut self,
        req: mayhttp::Request<'_, '_, '_>,
        rsp: &mut mayhttp::Response<'_>,
    ) -> io::Result<()> {
        let mut redirect = false;
        let mut path;
        let asset = match req.path() {
            "/" | "/index.html" => {
                path = "index.html".to_string();
                Assets::get("index.html")
            }
            _ => {
                path = req.path().trim_start_matches('/').to_string();
                if path.ends_with('/') {
                    path += "index.html";
                    redirect = true;
                    debug!("{path} extended for index.html");
                } else if !path.contains('.') {
                    path += "/index.html";
                    redirect = true;
                    debug!("{path} extended for /index.html");
                }
                let mut asset = Assets::get(&path);
                if asset.is_some() && REDIRECT_INDEX && redirect {
                    redirect = false;
                    debug!("{path} asset found");
                } else if asset.is_none() && !REDIRECT_INDEX && redirect {
                    asset = Assets::get("index.html");
                    debug!("{path} retrieves /index.html asset");
                }
                asset
            }
        };

        if let Some(content) = asset {
            let content_type = MimeMapper::instance()
                .get_or_insert(mime_guess::from_path(&path).first_or_octet_stream());
            // or:
            // let content_type =
            //     mime_mapper::mime_map(&mime_guess::from_path(&path).first_or_octet_stream());
            rsp.header(content_type)
                .body_mut()
                .extend_from_slice(&content.data);
            info!("{path} 200 OK");
        } else if redirect {
            rsp.header("Location: /")
                .status_code(307, "Temporary Redirect")
                .body("Temporary Redirect");
        } else {
            // Not Found
            rsp.status_code(404, "Not Found").body("Not Found");
            info!("{path} 404 Not Found");
        }

        Ok(())
    }
}

struct HttpServer;

impl mayhttp::HttpServiceFactory for HttpServer {
    type Service = Router;

    fn new_service(&self, _: usize) -> Self::Service {
        Router
    }
}

fn main() {
    let _ = may::config().set_pool_capacity(500).set_stack_size(0x1000);

    env_logger::init();

    info!("starting server");

    let http_server = HttpServer;
    let server = http_server.start(SERVER_ADDRESS).unwrap();

    info!("server listening at: {SERVER_ADDRESS}");

    server.join().unwrap();
}


And the mime_mapper.rs:
use std::{
    collections::HashMap,
    sync::{LazyLock, RwLock},
};

const CT_APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM: &str = "Content-Type: application/octet-stream";

static MIME_MAPPINGS: LazyLock<MimeMapper> = LazyLock::new(MimeMapper::default);

type MimeMap = RwLock<HashMap<mime_guess::Mime, &'static str>>;

#[derive(Debug, Default)]
pub(crate) struct MimeMapper {
    mappings: MimeMap,
}

/// `MimeMapper` uses [`mime_guess`] to create a _Content-Type_ header and
/// stores it once in a global static [`HashMap`].
impl MimeMapper {
    /// This returns a global static instance
    #[inline]
    pub(crate) fn instance() -> &'static Self {
        &MIME_MAPPINGS
    }

    pub(crate) fn get_or_insert(&self, mime: mime_guess::Mime) -> &'static str {
        if let Ok(m) = self.mappings.read() {
            if let Some(ct) = m.get(&mime) {
                return ct;
            }
        }

        if let Ok(mut m) = self.mappings.write() {
            if let Some(ct) = m.get(&mime) {
                return ct;
            }
            let ct: &'static str =
                Box::leak(("Content-Type: ".to_string() + mime.as_ref()).into_boxed_str());
            let _ = m.insert(mime, ct);
            return ct;
        }

        CT_APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM
    }
}

/// Alternative possibility without [`mime_guess`] and creating the roughly
/// half dozen required possibilities in a custom matcher.  
/// Needs to be extended for the required mime types.
#[inline]
#[allow(dead_code)]
pub(crate) fn mime_map(mime: &mime_guess::Mime) -> &'static str {
    match mime.as_ref() {
        "text/html" => "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8",
        "image/jpeg" => "Content-Type: image/jpeg",
        "image/png" => "Content-Type: image/png",
        "image/svg+xml" => "Content-Type: image/svg+xml",
        "text/css" => "Content-Type: text/css",
        "text/javascript" => "Content-Type: text/javascript",
        "text/plain" => "Content-Type: text/plain",
        "text/xml" => "Content-Type: text/xml",
        _ => CT_APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM,
    }
}


Thank youu, but the version I want to create is not the one using a redirect. Instead, I want it to directly return the index.html if not found. Because if using a redirect, it would go back to the beginning, which means passing through the middleware and routing processing again, adding unnecessary reprocessing that could actually be avoided. I will try to edit it first to match what I want

I tried running the full code earlier without modifying it first to test it, and for the content type error, even though I used solution 1, for some reason, it still appeared. But when I switched to solution 2, it was gone. However, the issue where only code or the favicon appears is still there. It rarely happens, but it still does if I refresh continuously. Earlier, I tried refreshing more than 20 times, and this is the message from debug log: [2024-10-17T11:49:36Z ERROR may_minihttp::http_server] service err = Custom { kind: BrokenPipe, error: 'closed' }. Do you have any suggestion?
